Close reason when the question becomes "obsolete" for the poster, without it being solved
This is my question: NotificationHub export job seems to be stuck in endless loop trying to write and delete test.json
This has been closed as "needs details or clarity" and I assume it will be automatically deleted soon. I suspect that it is closed due to my comment saying that the problem eventually resolved itself, however that is not what the close reason says.
While I understand that the question is not as acutely relevant for me anymore, if I were another person looking for the same problem now I'd would find it valuable that I can see that other people had the same problem, even if just to know that it in my case just resolved itself after a while.
If the intention is to close questions where the problem for the author is "obsolete" rather than "resolved", wouldn't it be clearer with a specific close reason for that? As a participant on this platform, having a question closed and deleted for lacking detail or clarity feels like I've done something wrong.

Without going further into question details, had you posted an answer "a few days ago", when the question was still open, and you found the problem sorted itself out; this wouldn't been an issue.

My 2cts, but when reading your Qt (on 'Main'), it's difficult to picture the scenario exactly (is there 1 'test.json' file?, or 2 files (1 for each job)?, or multiple files (1 new file every 5 min)? because the whole post is a mishmash of grammatical Singular/Plural, starting from the first sentence ("We have webjobs [Pl] that exports [Sg]"), + "these two instances [Pl] does [Sg]", + "When we delete the test.json [Sg?] manually they [Pl] get recreated"... // For "details", you could add a few entries from the Log file, which is what other Users would probably use to search the Web.

@chivracq Thank you for the feedback, plural/singular has always been an issue for me so I buy that. Too late to be a native speaker but I will try to pay more attention to that.

"I suspect that it is closed due to my comment saying that the problem eventually resolved itself, however that is not what the close reason says." I genuinely can't understand the reason for this suspicion. Why should "needs details or clarity" mean something different from "needs details or clarity"? Maybe the close reason says that because people actually think the question is unclear or missing details, and the fact that you are no longer experiencing the problem... isn't relevant to that judgment?

Not sure if this applies to your post but a self-resolving/obsolete question might be closable as 'Not reproducible or was caused by typos.'

"As a participant on this platform, having a question closed and deleted for lacking detail or clarity feels like I've done something wrong." - well... kind of. But not in the "go to your room" way. The tricky part behind "needs more details" is that as a potential answerer, you can't always really say which details are missing. The only thing you can positively know is that with what is given it is impossible to answer, so "need more". What? Yeah... whatever you can dig up, author of question. It's your burden.

@KarlKnechtel It's actually quite simple, the question was up for three weeks gathering around 40 views. No comments, no votes, no answers.  After three weeks I commented that the zombie job had disappeared and the day after the question was closed. It's simple Bayesian probability.


"if the intention is to close questions where the problem for the author is "obsolete" rather than "resolved""

That's not the intention at all. The close voters felt the question lacked information to be able to be answered by a third party.
You seem to be interpreting the closure incorrectly.
The close reason simply means that the close-voters do not think the question is answerable in its current state.
Looking at it superficially, (and recognizing I am not an Azure Guru), I don't think there is much to salvage in that question that could be useful to future readers.
But, in the general case, confronted with this close reason, if you wanted the question reopened you would need to add more information, so the question could be more adequately handled by other users.
Of course, I understand this is not particularly alluring if you are no longer invested in the question; so you might as well let it go.

It's worth noting that there is a close reason for questions where the issue can no longer be reproduced, such as a transient failure in a third-party service or something like that. That closure might fit this question, based on the comment. But that was not the close reason chosen/applied. As noted, the question was closed because 3 users thought it lacked sufficient information. That can be addressed via edits and the question can be re-opened. Or, I can just re-close for the not-reproducible reason. Based on the comment, it doesn't seem an answer would be useful to future viewers.

"The issue can no longer be reproduced" is different from what the poster asks, which is "I believe the question was closed because it became obsolete to me". That the problem no longer interests the OP doesn't mean is not reproducible (if enough details are present, to be able to attempting reproducing the issue). I don't think "it's not reproducible" necessarily fits the bill here, but I'm not delving in the specifics of the question, but simply in the incorrect interpretation of the close-reason.

Yes, I agree. That's why I noted that it was worth noting, not that it was the answer to the question. :-)

BTW, nice to you back, even if the glasses remain folded.

IMO the closure at least is incorrect, OPs question was clear, they submitted a job and were supposed to give it certain permissions but failed to do so, now the job is stuck in a loop and they want to cancel / kill / stop the job. Personally I can't seem to find any documentation to do so and the answer is probably "contact customer support".

@AbdulAzizBarkat if the closure is correct or incorrect, so be it. We have votes for that. What's positively incorrect is the OP interpretation of the meaning of the closure here. (Although I personally tend to agree that this looks like a "contact support" scenario, which would be a different close reason)

@yivi If the reason really is that the question lacked enough information then yes I was wrong about this. However I can't see what more information I can give. I showed the complete code of initializing the job, I described the whole problem, I gave all the relevant information about what the logs says (whish was not much). I don't know what more info I or any one else could provide here.

@Alex If you want to argue the question shouldn't be closed, be my guest. From the votes, I can deduce other users thought there were some details or clarity missing from the question. I won't argue about the closure itself. What I'm trying to do is dispel this misconception your question here was about: that your question was "closed" simply because you declared it was no longer relevant for you.

@yivi Thank you, that is understood.
